# When telneting with expect, how to grep an output word as the next command input variable via expect_out ?

Tags: bash, expect, telnet, spawn

I am trying to connect a device from telnet with expect command in bash script. What I would like to do is something as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

    telnet_setup()
 {      sleep 10
        expect <<EOF
        spawn telnet $1
        expect "Password:"
        send "mypass\n"
        expect "#"
        send "my command to be run\n"
        expect "Last number to be captured:" 
#Here the whole sentence to be captured something like:
#Last number to be captured: 213124
        set mynumber expect_out(buffer,0) | awk '{print $6}' 
        send "my next command with number $mynumber\"
        expect "Correct number $mynumber is achieved!"
        send "exit\n"
EOF

}
```

> To use the function, I use as follows:

```
telnet_setup 1.1.1.1 > file.txt
```

My goal is to use this function with $mynumber to be used in the next commands. Can you please suggest how to provide this?

Comment: Your shebang is expect. Why the heredoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having some trouble separating expect code from shell code. To capture the number, expect a regular expression with capturing parentheses

```
    send "my command to be run\r"
    expect -re {Last number to be captured:\s+(\d+)} 
    set mynumber $expect_out(1,string)
```